# Trash files inside user-selected folder inside iCloud Drive

Tags: file, cocoa, delete-file, macos-catalina, recycle-bin

My app works with user txt-files (create, change, delete) inside any user-selected folder. I just internally store the bookmark to get access to that user-selected folder and files.

Now, with macOS Catalina when the source folder is inside iCloud Drive, system still allows me to create and edit files. **But doesn't allow to trash one.** When I try to do it via `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] trashItemAtURL: ... ]` I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code=3328 

"<filename> couldn’t be moved to the trash
because the volume “<APFS volume name>”
doesn’t have one."

UserInfo={
NSURL=file:///... <filepath>.txt,
NSUserStringVariant=Trash
}
```

---

*Note: this only happens when the app is sandboxed.*

**Any ideas how to get the file trashed correctly?**

---

P.S. I know there is a `NSWorkspace recycle...` method, but it makes an extra deletion prompt that is not suitable for me.

P.P.S. I am still able to use `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL: ...]` method, but I need the target file to be restorable in case user changes his mind.

Comment: Curiously, I get the same error when I try to _detect_ if a file is inside the iCloud trash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64663834/43615 - and in my case the app is not even sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Looks like it's a rare case. But if you've got into the same situation, here is what I've ended up with:

There is a deprecated function - `FSMoveObjectToTrashSync` - that still works just fine. It saved my ass for now.

Comment: Unfortunately `FSMoveObjectToTrashSync` doesn't seem to be available in Swift.